# Chrome Extension Content-Security-Policy throwing errors, while it's set on *

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I've tried all possible setups for the CSP settings in my manifest.json, this is my current (very open and unsafe, I know).

When I open the background inspect for the extension, the first time after reloading it's fine, sometimes up until the fifth time, and then all of a sudden the errors below start pouring in..

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';"
```

And still I'm getting the following error

> Refused to load the script 'https://myapp-12345.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=1234567&cb=15&v=5' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

#### What I've tried

- Removing the chrome extension when I change the manifest.json

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: 1) The error message says there's no `*` in script-src 2) Why don't you specify the domain myapp-12345.firebaseio.com instead of `*`?

Comment: Because that's also not working, So I'm trying to loosen up the rules to see what's going on.

Comment: Since it should work and usually works, apparently you've encountered a bug in Chrome. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com or report it yourself otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

## You can only relax CSP in Chrome extensions to a certain extent

`"content_security_policy"` entry in Chrome Extension manifest allows developers to relax the CSP to a certain extent only. The subset of values allowed for `style-src` is very limited, quote from the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script):

> Currently, **developers can allowlist origins with the following
>   schemes: blob, filesystem, https, and chrome-extension**. The host part
>   of the origin must explicitly be specified for the https and
>   chrome-extension schemes. Generic wildcards such as https:, https://*
>   and https://*.com are not allowed; ...

Many of the values specified in your CSP (eg. `*` and `'unsafe-inline'` for `script-src`) are not valid in `"content_security_policy"` and Chrome ignores them (with a warning) when parsing `manifest.json`.

## Why you don't see warnings or errors about the invalid CSP values

I suspect that you might be checking errors in JavaScript console of the background page. You need to check the errors and warnings generated for your `manifest.json` first. Go to `chrome://extensions/` and click on the *Errors* button for your extension. There will be several warnings such as this:

> content_security_policy': Ignored insecure CSP value "*" in directive
>   'script-src'.

**Edit:**
I just noticed that the Errors page (`chrome://extensions/?errors=<extension-id>`) behaves inconsistently. There seems to be a bug that causes the warnings about ignored CSP values to only show up after reloading the extension.

## Links to documentation:

[`"content_security_policy"` in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

[`"content_security_policy"` in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy)
(The specification is basically identical but I find the documentation on MDN nicer and easier to follow.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't see the warnings in my extension errors page, but only in the popup page inspector. What does that say?

Comment: That is strange. If you have fundamentally incorrect values in your `manifest.json`, there should be warnings on the extension's errors page. Have you tried reloading the extension by clicking the circular arrow button on Extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`)? As I mentioned in my edit, Chrome seems to be inconsistent with the warnings and show them only after reloading in some cases.

Comment: I have, it's very bizarre, it also loops the requests for firebase, every second the error is thrown, but it only happens after 5 minutes (when I re-unpack the app).